# Difference between Editor: Trim Auto Whitespace and Files: Trim Trailing Whitespace in VSCode Settings

Tags: visual-studio-code

What is the difference between the `Editor: Trim Auto Whitespace` and `Files: Trim Trailing Whitespace` settings in VSCode? They seem like redundant settings, so I want to understand how they differ.

Answer (score 1):

If you go ahead to Code >> Preferences >> Settings >> Search 'Trim'.

Here's what is mentioned:

Editor: Trim Auto Whitespace
 - Remove trailing auto inserted whitespace

Files: Trim Trailing Whitespace:
 - When enabled, will trim trailing whitespace when saving a file.

The significance here is that they are both pretty similar.  The major difference is that the 'Files: Trim Trailing Whitespace" option trims your whitespace upon *saving a file*.

Comment: It's important to know what "auto inserted whitespace" is